# Coercible and existential

Tags: haskell, gadt, coercion, existential-type

```
data T t where
  A :: Show (t a) => t a -> T t
  B :: Coercible Int (t a) => t a -> T t

f :: T t -> String
f (A t) = show t

g :: T t -> Int
g (B t) = coerce t
```

Why does `f` compile but `g` generate an error like follows? I'm using GHC 8.4.

```
• Couldn't match representation of type ‘Int’ with that of ‘t a’
  Inaccessible code in
    a pattern with constructor:
      B :: forall k (t :: k -> *) (a :: k).
           Coercible Int (t a) =>
           t a -> T t,
    in an equation for ‘g’
• In the pattern: B t
  In an equation for ‘g’: g (B t) = coerce t
```

Also, are `Coercible` constraints zero-cost even when they are embedded in GADTs?

UPD: Compiler bug: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/15431

Comment: The issue is that GHC doesn't know what how to use a `Coercible Int (t a)`. The error message becomes a tiny bit clearer if you swap out `Coercible Int (t a)` for `Int ~ t a`. OTOH, something like `Coercible [Int] (t a)` is fine, since you are coercing from from type constructor to type constructor.

Comment: `g (B t) = 42` already triggers the error. It seems the issue lies in pattern matching, not in the use of `coerce`. Maybe, for some reason, the constraint is _required_ in the pattern matching, instead of _provided_ (as one would expect with GADTs)?

Comment: @chi It’s not required, not directly. The compiler believes that the constraint is impossible and is saying that the entire equation is therefore unreachable. I think Alec is on to something: however GHC is checking the constraint may have confused representational equality with propositional equality (a bug). That is my hypothesis.

Comment: @HTNW It is quite weird. Using `Int` triggers "Inaccessible code". Using `Identity Int` does that as well. Using `[Int]` instead is OK. Maybe GHC needs to know that `t` is representational, but there's no way to specify that.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you may replace the constraint (which is not free in the first place) with a `Data.Type.Coercion.Coercion` (which adds an extra `data` wrapper around the dictionary).

```
data T t where
  A :: Show (t a) => t a -> T t
  B :: !(Coercion Int (t a)) -> t a -> T t
    -- ! for correctness: you can’t have wishy-washy values like B _|_ (I "a")
    -- Such values decay to _|_
f :: T t -> String
f (A x) = show x
f (B c x) = show (coerceWith (sym c) x)

newtype I a = I a
main = putStrLn $ f $ B Coercion $ I (5 :: Int)
```

GHC 8.6 will improve this situation in two ways:

- Your original code will work, as the underlying bug was fixed.
- The `Coercion` can be unpacked to a `Coercible` constraint, and this will happen automatically, due to `-funbox-small-strict-fields`. Thus, this `T` will get performance characteristics equivalent to your original for free.

Comment: I'd try to `UNPACK` that, hoping that it becomes free. I'm unsure about what would happen, though.

Comment: @chi There is currently no way whatsoever to unpack a `Coercible` constraint. I opened a GHC proposal about that, but it's dormant. The `Coercion` itself will be unpacked by the default `-funbox-small-strict-fields` when compiling with optimization.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't think `Coercion` is unpacked. At least, an explicit `{-# UNPACK #-}` emits a "this does nothing" warning, so I can't see why `-funbox-small-strict-fields` would work.

Comment: @HTNW, `Coercion` should unpack to `Coercible`, which is not itself unpacked. The best way to check is to use `-ddump-simpl` and look at the code for the constructor wrapper. I'm pretty surprised by that warning. What version are you using?

Comment: @dfeuer 8.4.3, -O2. -Wall tells me the UNPACK is unusable. -ddump-simpl shows that the constructor wrapper takes a full Coercion, evaluates it, and stores it wholesale. EDIT: It works on HEAD.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed the fact that the former inability of GADTs to unpack (ever) affected `Coercion` too. There's still a restriction on existentials, but I think that can usually be worked around.